# How can I create a Moving Sum with a Lead using Prco Expand?

Tags: sas

I need to calculate a moving sum with a 10 day lead in SAS.  I'm assuming that proc expand is likely the best way to do this.  I can do this with the below code.  But I would like to eliminate the data step and decrease the number of lines used in proc expand if possible.

```
proc expand data=averages out=transformed;

id dt;

convert x=x_lead_10 / transform=(lead 10);
convert x=x_lead_11 / transform=(lead 11);
convert x=x_lead_12 / transform=(lead 12);
convert x=x_lead_13 / transform=(lead 13);
convert x=x_lead_14 / transform=(lead 14);
convert x=x_lead_15 / transform=(lead 15);
convert x=x_lead_16 / transform=(lead 16); 

data formatted;
set work.transformed;
x_sum = sum(x_lead_10,x_lead_11,x_lead_12,x_lead_13,x_lead_14,x_lead_15,x_lead_16)
run;
```

What I have works, but I'm trying to find a more efficient way to code this.  I'm doing this for multiple variables which makes my code get crowded quickly.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `proc expand` but there are a few `transform-sum` options you ma be able to take advantage of here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect026.htm

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by a 10 day lead with moving sum. I noticed that you haven't used a TRIM option either, have you looked into that?

Comment: @Reeza I'm trying to get row one to be a summation of rows 10 through 16, then I want row two to be a summation or rows 11 through 17 etc...  I haven't looked into the TRIM option, I'm reading about that now.  Thanks.

Comment: Use TRIMLEFT or TRIMRIGHT in your PROC EXPAND code. I actually have no idea how your code relates to your question. You should be doing a MOVESUM with the TRIM. It's best to include sample data that demonstrates your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exact but should help you get very close. The x_movSum is the value you want but not in the cell you want, it's in the 11th row, which is the sum of the previous 10 points. 
EDIT: It's now exact, see the new code below.

Anyways, here's how your code should be structured and the calculation:

```
*create sample data to work with;
data random;
    call streaminit(25);

    do date='01Jan2016'd to '31Dec2016'd;
        x=round(Rand('normal', 100, 15), 0.01);
        output;
        format date date9.;
    end;
run;

*Modified calculation;
proc expand data=random out=want;
    id date;
        convert x= x_movSum /transformout = (movsum 10 trimleft 9); /*This is the correct calculation expected*/
convert x = x_movSumFIRST / transformout = (reverse movsum 10 trimleft 9 reverse);*Correct numbers moved up to first record;
run;

* the manual way to do this in a data step. Depending on how much customization you need this may be easier;
data check;
    set want;
    array _t (0:9) _temporary_;
    _t(mod(_n_, 10))= x;

    if _n_ > 10 then
        do;
            check = sum(of _t(*));
        end;
run;
```

Comment: MOVSUM is really what I was I needed to be using.  With that like you said, I have the right value in the wrong cell.  I can easily shift that to where I need it.  Great solution.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think the second one is what you want, basically add the REVERSE to before and after to have it move up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the LEAD transformation with the MOVSUM transformation.

```
convert x=want2 / transformout=(lead 10 reverse movsum 7 reverse) ;
```

So if your series is just 1,2,3,..... then the first calculated value will be 11+12+13+14+15+16+17 = 98.

Comment: I thought this too, but it doesn't match the calculations from the other method. Not sure why, using SAS 9.4TS1M3. I tried movsum 10 and just with TRIM, MOVSUM/REVERSE.

Comment: Doesn't match what you posted, but does match the code used in the question.

Comment: I'll post a full example on SAS communities. I don't know why the first number is always wrong...or even how it's calculated. Every number after matches and that's my confusion. BTW I'm assuming that I'm missing something here, which is usually the case :)